# In Excel is there a way to copy and paste from one column to another when there are filters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

When there is filter which give discontinued numbered visible rows, Excel usual copy and paste does not work for all visible rows : you have to copy and paste multiple times.

Is there a way to do copy and paste in one single pass ?

Update : OK I forgot to tell I want to copy from one column to another column. In such situation I have to select and copy multiple times that even seem like an excel bug for me : though I selected whole column to copy when pasting only first ones are copied.

Comment: Can't you remove the filter, then copy/paste?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you having trouble copying all visible rows in a filtered list?

Comment: @LPChip do you think I’m stupid :) The reasons I want to filter is I don’t want to copy formula in whole column

Comment: You really need to work on your explanation. Even the edit in your question does nothing to highlight what you want to achieve. Post screenshots or sample data. Imagine we can't see your screen or read your mind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The visible rows in column C have been copied and pasted into C18. All four rows are there.

The same cells have been pasted into cell G1. It appears that not all cells have been pasted, but they have. The "missing" cells are in rows 2 and 4. Once the filter is removed from column B, these rows will be displayed and the cells will show.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I forgot to say something see my post update